# Insert into 2 tables with one form with 2 sql statements not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I am attempting to insert into 2 tables at once from one form.
table #1= bath_orders
table #2= customers
I am obviously trying to build an email list simultaneously.

The PHP skips the first INSERT INTO command and jumps to the second and continues to execute the remainder of the code on the page.

I find the several of the following errors upon each execution in my error log file:

> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: on line

I have searched the topic and found that in most cases people have erroneously attempted

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO bath_orders, customers ...."
```

But that is not the case in my code.
My code is as follows:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "my_user_name";
$password = "my_password";
$dbname = "my_database";

//  connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check 
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){


$fname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['fname']);
$lname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['lname']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['phone']);
$custaddress = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['custaddress']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['city']);
$state = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['state']);
$zip = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['zip']);
$pic1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pic1']);
$pic2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pic2']);
$pic3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pic3']);
$startdate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['startdate']);
$walltiledemo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['walltiledemo']);
$walltile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['walltile']);
$otherwalltile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherwalltile']);
$otherwalltileh = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherwalltileh']);
$otherwalltilew = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherwalltilew']);
$walltileinst = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['walltileinst']);
$pandemo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pandemo']);
$paninst = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['paninst']);
$flrtileinst = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['flrtileinst']);
$flrtile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['flrtile']);
$otherflrtile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherflrtile']);
$tub = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['tub']);
$newtub = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['newtub']);
$othertub = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['othertub']);
$door = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['door']);
$newdoor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['newdoor']);
$otherdoor = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherdoor']);
$floortiledemo = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['floortiledemo']);
$floortileinst = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['floortileinst']);
$floortile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['floortile']);
$otherfloortile = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherfloortile']);
$otherfloortileh = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherfloortileh']);
$otherfloortilew = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['otherfloortilew']);
$vanity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['vanity']);
$newvanity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['newvanity']);
$othervanity = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['othervanity']);




$sql = "INSERT INTO bath_orders (firstname, lastname, email, phone , custaddress , city , state , zip , pic1 , pic2 , pic3 ,  startdate , walltiledemo , walltile , otherwalltile , otherwalltileh , otherwalltilew , walltileinst , pandemo , paninst , flrtileinst , flrtile , otherflrtile , tub , newtub , othertub , door , newdoor , otherdoor , floortiledemo , floortileinst , floortile , otherfloortile , otherfloortileh , otherfloortilew , vanity , newvanity , othervanity)
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$phone', '$custaddress' , '$city' , '$state' , '$zip' , '$pic1' , '$pic2' , '$pic3' , '$startdate' , '$walltiledemo' , '$walltile' , '$otherwalltile' , '$otherwalltileh' , '$otherwalltilew' , '$walltileinst' , '$pandemo' , '$paninst' , '$flrtileinst' , '$flrtile' , '$otherflrtile' , '$tub'  , '$newtub' , '$othertub' , '$door' , '$newdoor' , '$otherdoor' , '$floortiledemo' , '$floortileinst' , '$floortile' , '$otherfloortile' , '$otherfloortileh' , '$otherfloortilew' , '$vanity' , '$newvanity' , '$othervanity' )";

$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (fname, lname, email, phone , custaddress , city , state , zip , comments )
VALUES ('$fname', '$lname', '$email', '$phone', '$custaddress' , '$city' , '$state' , '$zip' , '$comments')";
```

I have researched the subject but.. I am not understanding what I am doing wrong.
It says to execute 2 separate INSERT INTO statements and I think that is what I am doing.

 Could someone please help me to understand what 2 separate statements should look like.

**TYIA**

Here is a link to a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/fiveonadub/836n4ycf/2/

Comment: I think I have figured out that the PHP errors that I am getting are from not having any values entered into those fields in the form upon submission. How can I avoid those errors if someone chooses not to enter a value?

Comment: "PHP Notice: Undefined variable: on line " which variable, on which line? Does it mention that at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to user `mysqli_query()`. The `mysqli_query()` function performs a query execution against the database.

Store first query in `$sql1` and second in `$sql2`

`mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);  mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);`

Comment: I have tried several different ways to implement your suggestion but nothing is working properly for me. I must not clearly understand.

Comment: Please add your `<form>` code in above question which will help me to produce same bug on my pc

Comment: Gru,
Thanks.
I edited my original post to include a link to a fiddle in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how your php  skips the first INSERT INTO command and jumps to the second.You didn't use mysqli_query() function for any one of that. Store the output of these 2 queries into 2 different variables and then pass that variable as parameter to mysqli_query(). Then only your query will get executed.

-Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

There are two thing that seem to go wrong here.

First, simply assigning an sql-looking string to a variable does not make it execute the sql on the server yet, you'll need to call some method or function to make that happen.

Second, and I only know this because I quickly copy/pasted your code into an IDE, but the $comments variable is not defined.

Comment: Additionally, I believe your code could greatly benefit from things like PDO and maybe a form library. Since all values seem to be escaped and proper quotation seems to be used, it's not directly at risk of sql injection, but it's, well, quite a bulk.